# Extracting all Latex commands from a Latex code File

Tags: python, regex, latex

I am trying to extract all the latex commands from a tex file. I have to use Python for this. I tried to extract the latex commands in a list using Re module.

The problem is that this list does not contain the latex commands whose name includes special characters (such as \alpha*, \a', \#, \$, +, :, \; etc). It only contains the latex commands that consist of letters.

I am presently using the re.match python command :

```
    "I already know the starting index of '\' which is at self.i.
     The example Latex code string could be:
     \documentclass[envcountsame,envcountchap]{svmono}"

     match_text = re.match("[\w]+", search_string[self.i + 1:])
```

I am able to extract 'documentclass'. But suppose there is another command like:

```
     "\abstract*[alpha]{beta}"
     "\${This is a latex document}"
     "\:"
```

How do I extract only 'abstract*', '$', ':' from these strings?

I am new to Python and tried various approaches, but am not able to extract all these command names. If there is a general python Regex that can handle all these cases, it would be useful.

NOTE: A book called 'The Not So Short introduction to LaTeX' defines that the format of LaTeX commands can be of three types -

> FORMATS:

- They start with a backslash \ and then have a name consisting of
  letters only. Command names are terminated by a space, a number or
  any other ‘non-letter.’
- They consist of a backslash and exactly one non-letter.
- Many commands exist in a ‘starred variant’ where a star is appended to the command name.

Comment: seems like `r'\\([a-zA-Z]+)(\*)?'` would be about right when used with `re.findall`...

Comment: For package commands, `@` is a letter, but that's a case you cannot catch without the larger context of the file, i.e. not reasonably with a regular expression.

Comment: `\abstract*[alpha]{beta}` is actually the command `\abstract` with three parameters, the asterisk itself, the optional second parameter and the normal parameter surrounded by braces, so why to act with the first parameter if it is an asterisk and not elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the exact translation of your format specification:

```
\\(?:[^a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]+)\*?
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bY0bE0/1)

- non-letter: `[^a-zA-Z]`
- or letters: `[a-zA-Z]+`
- starred variant: `\*?`

If your format description is accurate, this should do it. Unfortunately I don't know LaTeX so I'm not sure it's 100% OK.

---

From the feedback in the comments, it turns out the star is applicable only to letter commands, and there can be some other terminating characters as well. The final regex is:

```
\\(?:[^a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]+[*=']?)
```

Comment: +1 There are no standard single-character commands that have a starred variant (as far as I can recall), so `\\(?:[^a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]+\*?)` (unchecked) would also work. There are various other cases (TeX's tokenizer is ... special) but this should get most of the commands, with few false positives, in a ‘normal’ document.

Comment: Thanks. Upvoting this. This seems to work out in most cases except one. Only one particular type of case is not being handled by this. We have certain latex commands that start with a letter and are terminated by a non-letter different from star. For example, " \a= " , " \a' " etc. If you can think of a slightly modified regex, would be great.

Comment: @shanu sure, it's pretty easy to modify if you have a list of the possible characters. `\\(?:[^a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]+[*=']?)` will work with the ones you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: As from *The TeX book*, and someone has included here, the spaces behind a multiletter command must be included in the command name (for delimiting purposes, not for matching command name) and so, your regex fails with something like `\begin         {}`.  A better regexp would be: `\\([A-Za-z]+ *|.|\n)`.  But be careful with commands like accented chars, as they appear somethink like `Espa\~nol` and you'll get undesired effects.  Starred commands are treated in `\LaTeX` as if their first parameter were an asterisk.  Why actually you want to eliminate `\LaTeX` stuff?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: The regex that you suggested is working great. But 2 days before, I came across a LaTeX command of the form (\@pnumwidth, \@evenhear, \c@page=). It seems that LaTeX treats '@' very differently. Since I did not give this info to you earlier, the regex here is only able to find '@' and not '@pnumwidth'. I have been trying to modify the regex but something else breaks. Do you have any workarounds for this?

Comment: @LuisColorado: I am doing a project in which I need to parse through a tex file and get a structure of all the LaTeX commands within the tex file. I am also keeping note of the squarebrace([ ]) and curlybrace({ }) parameter, if present, associated with each LaTeX command.

Comment: As mentioned by @ulrich Schwarz on the top, in package commands, LaTeX treats '@' as a letter. Semantically, we understand what it does, but I cannot figure out how to make a regex expression understand this fact.

Comment: If `@` should be treated like a letter, simply add it to the pattern where the letters are defined: `\\(?:[^a-zA-Z@]|[a-zA-Z@]+[*=']?)` and if that makes something else break, I'd need an example to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

LaTeX is a TeX macro package, and as so, all that's applicable to TeX is also applicable to LaTeX.

The question you ask is a difficult one, as TeX is not a regular language.  If you want only to deal with commands, you have to check for `\\([A-Za-z]+ *|.|\n)` regex (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bY0bE0/3)), with the notice that in TeX you have *active characters*, that is, characters for which the only presence acts like a command.  If you want to deal with command parameters, you'll have to check the individual command definitions, because TeX is a Polish Notation (operators or commands are prefix, with a variable number of positional parameters) language.  For parameter extraction, TeX uses brace matching which is context free and not regular, so you'll need a complete parser for that.

TeX allows you to redefine all character classes, so you can redefine the digits to act as letters, and be usable as command names (so for example `\a23` is a valid command name) (this happens inside the package definitions, where the `@` is used as a letter, to be able to make commands that are inaccessible to users, but available inside the package)

Eliminating LaTeX markup is a difficult thing for this reason and you can only achieve partial results.  There are many different problems to be solved (what to do with `\include` directives, what to do with valid text in parameters like `\chapter` parameters or `\footnote`, you want the index included, etc.)

Also, you have to be carefull, as if you try to eliminate command parameters, you'll be also eliminating part of your text (for example the text in `\footnote`, `\abstract`, `\title`, `\chapter{...}`, etc.)  I don't know the effect you actually want to get, so I cannot give you more info in this respect.